# how to implement imageview in gridview

Tags: android, gridview

i have two int array of images , i have implemented it in grid view . i want to set image from  another array on clicking the item on grid? I tried by creating object of imageview globally but its getting force close.

```
package com.sachin.majum;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import android.R.integer;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
public class select extends Activity {
ImageView im = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
int blank [] =                  {R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launche r,R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher};
int image []={R.drawable.dc,R.drawable.dd,R.drawable.kkr,R.drawable.mi,R.drawable.rcb,R.drawable.rr,R.drawable.dc,R.drawable.dd,R.drawable.kkr,R.drawable.mi,R.drawable.rcb,R.drawable.rr};
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.select);
 Random random =  new Random();
 List intlist = new ArrayList();
 for(int i=0;i<image.length;i++)
 {
     intlist.add(image[i]);
 }
 Collections.shuffle(intlist,random);
 for(int i=0;i<intlist.size();i++)
 {
     image[i]=(Integer) intlist.get(i);
 }
 GridView grid = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gv);
 grid.setAdapter(new MyAdapter());
 grid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
im.setImageResource(image[position]);
     }
 });

}

class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return blank.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    im.setImageResource(blank[position]);
    im.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(60,60));
    return im;
}

}
}
```

`

Comment: if you have all the images right at the starting why you using blank images array and even that is also of the same image multiple times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `onClickListener` code.

```
grid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
         ImageView iV = (ImageView)v;
         iV.setImageResource(image[position]);
     }
});
```

and remove this declaration, you don't need it.

```
ImageView im = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create an ImageView for each cell of the Gridview. I've adapted your getView to reflect this change:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null){
      convertView = new ImageView( select.this );
    }

    ((ImageView)convertView).setImageResource(blank[position]);
    ((ImageView)convertView).setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(60,60));
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: its getting force close, if i make change in getView method .

Comment: and how will i change the image in gridView. onItemClick

Comment: 06-24 17:17:30.144: E/AndroidRuntime(404): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.sachin.majum/com.sachin.majum.select}: java.lang.NullPointerException